# Error Code: 1292 Truncated incorrect datetime value

Tags: mysql

```
insert into test_date 
select  
    shopify_update
from `vw_shopify_json_price` 
where cache_id=669
```

> Error Code: 1292
>   Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2019-05-17T11:34:30-04:00'

```
CREATE TABLE `test_date` (
  `t` datetime DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome on stack overflow. A bit of context on what you try to do and what did not work will help the community help you.

Answer (score 1):

`datetime` does not allow a timezone or timezone offset. Some reasonable choices:

1. convert the timestamp to UTC and store that (my recommendation)
2. convert the timestamp to the timezone of your database and store that

Comment: I tried these two formats but not succeeded, do you have any other idea

date_format(shopify_update,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.000Z')
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(shopify_update,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.000Z'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')

Comment: I think you might get rid of this part of the format str: `.000Z` (that's probably adding in the timezone offset). In particular, you might need it when reading the existing data, but don't use it when writing to the DB.

Comment: now its successful but showing warning.

Warning Code : 1292
Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2019-05-17T11:34:30-04:00'

Comment: datetime as you see above

Comment: My guess: `shopify_update` is not actually of type `datetime`. Can you show the output of this command: `describe vw_shopify_json_price;`

Comment: it is a database view and output of command

shopify_update datetime YES  \N

Comment: Can you run these commands and update with the output? `SELECT @@GLOBAL.time_zone, @@SESSION.time_zone;` and `SELECT shopify_update FROM vw_shopify_json_price WHERE cache_id=669;`

Comment: SYSTEM SYSTEM 2019-05-17 11:34:30

Comment: Now what happens if you run the original: `INSERT INTO test_date SELECT shopify_update FROM vw_shopify_json_price WHERE cache_id=669;`

Comment: Error Code: 1292 Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2019-05-17T11:34:30-04:00'

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue, which was caused by the date time field being stored as **varchar**.

The issue was resolved by doing this:

1) Taking first 10 characters of the timestamp

2) Converting it to date.

```
where str_to_date(left(my_future_date,10), '%Y-%m-%d') > now()
```

P.S. this is a hacky way, but i did not want to go through all the code related to this field, and doing all the changes.  This solved my issue in 30 seconds.  But solution took half an hour to find.